# Django different 404 Errors on Production

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have product pages and tag pages on my website. For the product query, I use the code: product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug), and for the Tag query, I use: tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=slug).

When running my code on my local machine with DEBUG set to True, I encounter a Django error page with a 404 status code. However, in my production environment, I experience different behaviors for the two types of pages.

For tag pages, like https://my.domain/tag/abrakadabra/, I correctly receive a 404 error page. However, for product pages, like https://my.domain/product/abrakadabra/, I encounter an internal server error instead of the expected 404 error page.

Interestingly, when I set DEBUG to True on my production server, I do receive the correct 404 Django error page for both tag and product pages.

Comment: Can you post your codes and error ??